# How to extend Python and make a C-package?

Tags: python, cpython, python-extensions, python-embedding

I embedded and extended Python 2.7 in my C application a while ago. Late on the train I am bringing it to Python 3, and a lot of initializations for the module registration changed for me.

Before I used `PyModule_Create` to create the module and added the members afterwards, even sub-modules so I could execute:

```
from foo.bar import bas
```

I added/appended the 'top-level' module to `PyEval_GetBuiltins()`, which might have been wrong in Py 2, but it worked. Now in Py 3 I receive this exception on the code above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo.bar'; 'foo' is not a package
```

Looking up the docs, I found now an example with `PyImport_ExtendInittab`. I have two questions regarding this:

1) What is `Inittab` supposed to mean? The doc says what it means, but this naming is slighly irritating. What is an `Inittab`? Shouldn't it be called `PyImport_ExtendBuiltins`, that I would understand.

2) I can only find examples where plain modules get added. Is creating a package with sub-modules possible with `PyImport_ExtendInittab` too?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A minimal example (i.e. [mcve])  would be a great help for understanding, what your are exactly doing (wrong). It is possible, that your issue is rather due to the fact that Python3 doesn't not support implicit relative import rather than something with module initialization.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. What are *foo*, *bar*, *bas*? How do your module package tree looks like in *Python 2*? How does the (simplified) source code look like?

Comment: Please share the module code (or at least a function and the initialization part), and a sample of how you invoke it from *Python 2*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if what you're trying to pull here (nested extension modules) is *OK*, anyway the recommended way for structuring code is via [[Python 3.Docs]: Modules - Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). 
However, I did this (reproducing the problem, fixing it) as a personal exercise.

### 1. Intro

Listing the 2 relevant pages:

- [[Python **3**.Docs]: Module Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#module-objects)
- [[Python **2**.Docs]: Module Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/module.html#module-objects)

The environment:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q061692747]> tree /a /f
> Folder PATH listing for volume SSD0-WORK
> Volume serial number is AE9E-72AC
> E:.
> |   test00.py
> |
> +---py2
> |       mod.c
> |
> \---py3
>         helper.c
>         mod.c
> ```

### 2. Python 2

Dummy module attempting to reproduce the behavior mentioned in the question.

*mod.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

#define MOD_NAME "mod"
#define SUBMOD_NAME "submod"


static PyObject *pMod = NULL;
static PyObject *pSubMod = NULL;

static PyMethodDef modMethods[] = {
    {NULL}
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC initmod() {
    if (!pMod) {
        pMod = Py_InitModule(MOD_NAME, modMethods);
        if (pMod) {
            PyModule_AddIntConstant(pMod, "i", -69);
            pSubMod = Py_InitModule(MOD_NAME "." SUBMOD_NAME, modMethods);
            if (pSubMod) {
                PyModule_AddStringConstant(pSubMod, "s", "dummy");
                if (PyModule_AddObject(pMod, SUBMOD_NAME, pSubMod) < 0) {
                    Py_XDECREF(pMod);
                    Py_XDECREF(pSubMod);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q061692747\py2]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "f:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualCForPython2\2008\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat" x64
> Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x64 tools.
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> mod.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\02.07.17\include" mod.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:mod.pyd /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\02.07.17\libs"
> mod.c
>    Creating library mod.lib and object mod.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> mod.c
> mod.exp
> mod.lib
> mod.obj
> mod.pyd
> mod.pyd.manifest
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_02.07.17_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
> Python 2.7.17 (v2.7.17:c2f86d86e6, Oct 19 2019, 21:01:17) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import sys
> >>>
> >>> [item for item in sys.modules if "mod" in item]
> []
> >>> import mod
> >>>
> >>> [item for item in sys.modules if "mod" in item]  # !!! NOTICE the contents !!!
> ['mod.submod', 'mod']
> >>>
> >>> mod
> <module 'mod' from 'mod.pyd'>
> >>> mod.i
> -69
> >>> mod.submod
> <module 'mod.submod' (built-in)>
> >>> mod.submod.s
> 'dummy'
> >>>
> >>> from mod.submod import s
> >>> s
> 'dummy'
> >>>
> ```

As seen, importing the module with submodules, adds the submodules in *sys.path* (didn't look, but I am *99.99%* sure this is performed by *Py_InitModule*)

### 3. Python 3

Conversion to *Python 3*. Since this is the 1<sup>st</sup> step, treat the 2 commented lines as they were not there.

*mod.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
//#include "helper.c"

#define MOD_NAME "mod"
#define SUBMOD_NAME "submod"


static PyObject *pMod = NULL;
static PyObject *pSubMod = NULL;

static PyMethodDef modMethods[] = {
    {NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef modDef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, MOD_NAME, NULL, -1, modMethods,
};

static struct PyModuleDef subModDef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, MOD_NAME "." SUBMOD_NAME, NULL, -1, modMethods,
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_mod() {
    if (!pMod) {
        pMod = PyModule_Create(&modDef);
        if (pMod) {
            PyModule_AddIntConstant(pMod, "i", -69);
            pSubMod = PyModule_Create(&subModDef);
            if (pSubMod) {
                PyModule_AddStringConstant(pSubMod, "s", "dummy");
                if (PyModule_AddObject(pMod, SUBMOD_NAME, pSubMod) < 0) {
                    Py_XDECREF(pMod);
                    Py_XDECREF(pSubMod);
                    return NULL;
                }
                //addToSysModules(MOD_NAME "." SUBMOD_NAME, pSubMod);
            }
        }
    }
    return pMod;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q061692747\py3]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
> **********************************************************************
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.23
> ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> **********************************************************************
> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> helper.c
> mod.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\include" mod.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:mod.pyd /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\libs"
> mod.c
>    Creating library mod.lib and object mod.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> helper.c
> mod.c
> mod.exp
> mod.lib
> mod.obj
> mod.pyd
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import sys
> >>>
> >>> [item for item in sys.modules if "mod" in item]
> []
> >>> import mod
> >>>
> >>> [item for item in sys.modules if "mod" in item]  # !!! NOTICE the contents !!!
> ['mod']
> >>>
> >>> mod
> <module 'mod' from 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q061692747\\py3\\mod.pyd'>
> >>> mod.i
> -69
> >>> mod.submod
> <module 'mod.submod'>
> >>> mod.submod.s
> 'dummy'
> >>>
> >>> from mod.submod import s
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod.submod'; 'mod' is not a package
> >>> ^Z
>
>
> [prompt]>
> ```

As seen, nested import is not possible. That is because *mod.submod* is not present in *sys.modules*. As a generalization, "nested" extension submodules are no longer made importable through the module that contains them initialization function. the only option is to import them manually. 
As a note: I think **this *Python 3* restriction is there for a reason, so what comes below is like playing with fire**.

**Decomment the 2 lines from *mod.c***.

*helper.c*:

```c
int addToSysModules(const char *pName, PyObject *pMod) {
    PyObject *pSysModules = PySys_GetObject("modules");
    if (!PyDict_Check(pSysModules)) {
        return -1;
    }
    PyObject *pKey = PyUnicode_FromString(pName);
    if (!pKey) {
        return -2;
    }
    if (PyDict_Contains(pSysModules, pKey)) {
        Py_XDECREF(pKey);
        return -3;
    }
    Py_XDECREF(pKey);
    if (PyDict_SetItemString(pSysModules, pName, pMod) == -1)
    {
        return -4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\include" mod.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:mod.pyd /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\libs"
> mod.c
>    Creating library mod.lib and object mod.exp
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>>
> >>> import sys
> >>>
> >>> [item for item in sys.modules if "mod" in item]
> []
> >>> import mod
> >>>
> >>> [item for item in sys.modules if "mod" in item]  # !!! NOTICE the contents :) !!!
> ['mod.submod', 'mod']
> >>>
> >>> from mod.submod import s
> >>> s
> 'dummy'
> >>>
> ```

### 4. Closing notes

As I stated above, this seems more like a workaraound. A cleaner solution would be to better organize the modules via packages.

Since this is for demo purposes, and to keep the code as simple as possible, I didn't always check *Python C API* functions return codes. This can lead to hard to find errors (even crashes) and **should never be done** (especially in production code).

I am not very sure what *PyImport_ExtendInittab* effect really is as I didn't play with it, but [[Python 3.Docs]: Importing Modules - int PyImport_ExtendInittab(struct _inittab *newtab)](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_ExtendInittab) states (**emphasis** is mine):

> **This should be called before [Py_Initialize()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Initialize)**.

So, calling it in our context, is out of the question.

Also mentioning this (old) discussion (not sure whether it contains relevant information, but still) [[Python.Mail]: [Python-Dev] nested extension modules?](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2002-August/028056.html).

Comment: Thank you soooo much for the insights! That definetely clarified a lot! I used your example but instead of the helper and combined ith with `PyImport_GetModuleDict` and that worked. Again, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Without a minimal reproducible example, it's hard to tell what's wrong and what specifically you're looking for in an answer. Nevertheless, I will attempt to provide some assistance.

```
from foo.bar import bas
```

For the above to work, you need a file *bar.py* in a folder called *foo*, and *bar.py* must contain a function `bas()`. Also, folder *foo* must contain an empty *__init__.py* file.

Now, if you want to call a compiled C file somewhere, then probably the easiest way to accomplish this would be to use `os.system()` or `subprocess.call()` and call the file as if you were calling it from the command line.

Assuming the make file is in the same directory:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.system("make run")

# or
subprocess.run("make run".split())
```

Where `make run` runs your C file as desired (declared in your makefile). Also feel free to pass in keyword arguments using python f-strings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is wrong for several reasons: 1. *OP* knows how to build their code, 2. Building code via *Python* -> *make* -> ... makes no sense and it's ugly, 3. *OP* wants to import the built code. -1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one year late with this answer, but, having stumbled upon the same problem as the OP, I believe I have found a cleaner solution than the accepted answer.

I'm only going to cover Python 3, as this is what the OP was looking to address and, well, it's 2021.

### The Problem

A built-in module, while following the same conventions as an extension module, would not be compiled into a shared library and distributed as a file – it makes  more sense to do this when [*embedding*](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) Python into a larger application, as the module should not be accessible to a general-purpose Python application or to the interactive interpreter.

A built-in module is registered to the interpreter using `PyImport_ExtendInittab`, as the OP had found. However, if the name is *nested* (e.g. `foo.bar.bas`, instead of `bas`), the default import machinery will not work.

### Issues with the Accepted Answer

The accepted answer loads the module and executes it as soon as it is registered to the interpreter (i.e. when the `PyMODINIT_FUNC` function is called). Subsequently importing the module from Python would simply return the object in `sys.modules`.

Additionally, this wouldn't work with the newer (and recommended) [Multi-Phase Initialization](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#multi-phase-initialization), which has consequences for the ability to reload a module and using sub-interpreters.

### The Cause of the Problem

The Python import machinery is very well [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). Any imported module (whether a shared-library-backed extension, built-in and registered via `PyImport_ExtendInittab` or pure Python) needs to be located by a `MetaPathFinder` registered in `sys.meta_path`. By default, built-in modules are located by `importlib.machinery.BuiltinImporter` (which happens to be a *Loader*, as well). However, its `find_spec` method is defined as:

```
    @classmethod
    def find_spec(cls, fullname, path=None, target=None):
        if path is not None:
            return None
        if _imp.is_builtin(fullname):
            return spec_from_loader(fullname, cls, origin=cls._ORIGIN)
        else:
            return None
```

A *nested* module (e.g. `foo.bar.bas`) is looked-up by calling the `find_spec` method using its parent's package `__path__` attribute as the second argument (i.e. `find_spec('foo.bar.bas', foo.bar.__path__)`.

This can be easily tested by setting up a pure Python parent package (e.g. `foo/bar/__init__.py` in the Python path) with:

```
__path__ = None
```

A built-in extension module named `foo.bar.bas` and registered via `PyImport_ExtendInittab` will then be importable.

This behaviour is somewhat [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-meta-path):

> Some meta path finders only support top level imports. These importers will always return None when anything other than None is passed as the second argument.

### The Solution

The test above is a bit of a hack that depends on knowledge of implementation details and, anyway, can only be considered a solution if no non-built-in modules would be desired beneath `foo.bar` – a pure Python module named `foo.bar.moo` (i.e. defined in `foo/bar/moo.py`) would fail to import in this case.

A much cleaner solution is to define a `MetaPathFinder`, which also seems to be [encouraged](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#replacing-the-standard-import-system):

> The most reliable mechanism for replacing the entire import system is to delete the default contents of sys.meta_path, replacing them entirely with a custom meta path hook.

Of course, we can retain the existing `MetaPathFinder`s, simply extending the list. The following code defined in `foo/bar/__init__.py` (relying exclusively on documented and non-deprecated APIs, at the time of this writing) would do the trick:

```
import importlib.abc
import importlib.machinery
import importlib.util
import sys


class CustomBuiltinImporter(importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder):
    _ORIGIN = 'custom-builtin'

    @classmethod
    def find_spec(cls, fullname, path, target=None):
        if path != __path__ or not fullname.startswith(cls.__module__ + '.'):
            return None
        if fullname not in sys.builtin_module_names:
            return None
        return importlib.util.spec_from_loader(fullname, importlib.machinery.BuiltinImporter, origin=cls._ORIGIN)


sys.meta_path.append(CustomBuiltinImporter)
```

This code will not allow built-in modules defined under anything other than `foo.bar` to be loaded. Of course, a custom `MetaPathFinder` can be defined anywhere (including in some bootstrapping code of the application), but the first test of the `find_spec` method would need adapting. Such an implementation would also allow `foo.bar` to be a [namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), thus providing even more flexibility for its contents.